# Combining Google Combo chart with 2 values with line chart

Tags: google-sheets

So I have 3 values which are, Percent, Target, and Overtime.

I want to show on the chart the percent with overtime as one stacked column chart, but for the target, I want to make it show as one line as it will be like a fixed value.

I have tried a lot but it didn't work for me at all. Does anybody have any idea how to get this working, please?

Here is the sheet for the chart: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pSyWYMzDFGDNkDTfv1LMurcsvrN6bx3GjxVbmqFijk8/edit#gid=0

Comment: I've made a couple changes in sheet "Test" which was copied from "Sheet1" I hope it will answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this were you looking for?

[image: Combo chart setting]

Chart editor: in `Customize` tab on `Series` setting you can change each one of `[Percent,Target,Overtime]` specifically to be type `[line, column, or more]` to make combo chart

I hope it'll help you

Comment: Excellent, thats what i wanted exactly. but can we make the overtime bars smaller? like i want the percent have the majority of the bar and the overtime is the minority. thank you so much <3

Comment: I'm happy to help. but about setting bars smaller, I think it doesn't have option for this. Somehow let try `Percent` bar change type to `Stepped area` but it still doesn't look good. I hope it may have other ways for you